# Округление при преобразовании double в decimal

Tags: c#, округление

При достаточно больших значениях double (с заданной целой частью) при его преобразовании в decimal происходит округление. Однако преобразование в long дает правильный результат.

```
double d = 1725040000979649;
long l = (long)d;
decimal result1 = (decimal)d; // 1725040000979650
decimal result2 = (decimal)l; // 1725040000979649
```

Почему так происходит? Можно ли как то преобразовать без округления?
Пробовал на 3.1 и 8.0 воспроизводить.

Comment: Это не округление, а приведение типа. Округление это математичнская операция, например `Math.Round`.

Comment: Возможно, это реальная проблема в коде приведения. Есть похожий issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72135, закрыт летом 2022 года. Возможно, фикс ещё не доехал до прода.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko это не реальная проблема, а подход, который был выбран для решения данной задачи. То есть просто нужно знать, что преобразование выполняется с таким подходом, а именно только 14 десятичных знаков. Чтобы что-то фиксить, нужно обосновать другой подход.

Comment: Возможно, этот подход основан на обратном преобразовании из Decimal в Double. Только 14 десятичных разрядов можно представить точно в Double.

Comment: @rotabor, но это кажется странным. `decimal` может хранить все цифры числа `double`, насколько я помню, он может хранить до 28-ми десятичных цифр. Почему при преобразовании отбрасываются цифры. Возможно, это действительно ошибка в коде, как так, на которую я привёл ссылку.

Answer (score 2):

Это какая-то особенность преобразования. 1725040000979649 очень близко к максимальному значению мантиссы для типа Double 179769313486232, и, видимо, дело именно в этом. Если убрать любую цифру, то всё будет норм.

41-45 округляется к 40, 46-49 округляется к 50.

Скорее всего, это сделано потому, что только диапазон 14-тиразрядных чисел может быть представлен точно полностью (до 99 999 999 999 999), поэтому 15-ый рязряд округляется.

Преобразовать без округления можно только так:

```
decimal result2 = (long)d;
```